# Changing only one value of a column wherein there are multiple data of the same value in SQL

Tags: sql, c

For example, I have a table:

User ID(int)    |     Card ID(int)    |     Deck(int)

```
   1841     |            14       |         1
   1841     |            14       |         1
```

it is defined that the int values in deck column would always take on 1 or 2 as a value(1 indicating that it is in the deck). and card ID is not unique for a user(this indicate that a user have 2 card 14) , as shown in the example above. what if i want to remove one card 14 in the deck and the other would remain. what is the proper sql command, i tried UPDATE but it

Comment: Why are you allowing duplicate cards to be created in the first place? I can't hold two ace of spade cards from the same deck in my hand at the same time. You should fix your database to add constraints that prevent this situation from being present, and then you don't have to figure out how to update only one of the rows.

Comment: Ken White. It a trading card game, so you can have many cards of the same type in a deck. :)

Comment: Then you need a way to make the rows distinct (separate from each other), like an ID column. Allowing exact duplicate rows is a headache if you need to later work with a single row, so the solution is *don't allow it in the first place*. If I have two trading cards that are exactly the same (one in each hand), and I start swapping them back and forth between hands, how do you know which one was originally held in my right hand when I'm finished? (The answer is that you don't, unless one of the cards is different to start with so you can track it. You have that same problem now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you're missing a way of referencing any single particular row. Depending how critical to the application is need for such reference, it is almost always bad idea to allow such situation. There are many solutions for this, for example

1) Every row usually contains unique OID or ROWID field , which is not displayed with "SELECT * FROM TABLE", but can be used if requested implicitly. Depending on what database engine you use, e.g. with PostgreSQL try

```
SELECT OID, * FROM TABLE WHERE OID = 'somevalue'
```

this is usually used if you don't want to enforce UNIQUE on the table, but rather deal with possible mistaken input later if it will unfortunately appear.

2) You can add ID column, for example autoincremental ( refer to DB manual ), and then update it to contain unique IDs

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name column-definition;
```

3) You can use self incrementing "running total", eg. with MySQL it looks more/less like this:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT *, (@runtot := @runtot + 1) AS rt FROM table WHERE rt='somevalue'
```

(this will do calculation every time so probably will be inefficient )

4) You can use LIMIT as explained in previous answer

5) You can JOIN some another table with unique IDs and possibly update resulting relation, or combine some query to create and use static VIEW

6) You can use SELECT with some dynamically allocated value, for example RAND() or NOW() or similar. It probably won't create unique identifiers across whole table, depending what function you'll use and how you will use it

7) combine two or more above solutions altogether

..and probably many other solutions. Anyway usually there's some "Id" column used with some UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: piotr wadas. :) i will try those solutions and implement it. specially the SELECT IOD.

Comment: Congratulations, you've just discovered another reason to avoid using MySQL. There is, but it cannot be used, because it is hidden as InnoDB internals. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: wew. we are required to use it.

Answer (score 1):

you can define limit at the end of update query

```
update [table name] set Deck=2 where User_ID=1841 and Card_id=14 limit 1;
```